# Less CSS "alias" with bootstrap + font-awesome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, font-awesome

My site uses `bootstrap` + `font-awesome` and I'm trying to create an "alias" in my `site.less` file:

```
.icon-domain { .icon-fire; }
.icon-group  { .icon-tags; }
```

The reason I'm doing this is because I have a "Domain" entity on my site and I might change the icon in the future so I don't want to directly use to the "fire" icon in my HTML.

The `icon-group` class works on my code but `icon-domain` does not. From what I can tell, its because font-awesome actually has an `icon-group` class in its code. From what I understood of `lesscss` I can include a class inside another class to combine them into a new class but its simply not working here.

I can get it to work if I do this in my `site.less`:

```
.icon-domain { &:before { content: "\f06d"; } }
```

But that is not ideal since I have to define the content myself and using `.icon-domain { .icon-fire; &:before; }` is a syntax error. Is there a anyway to make this work properly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import Font Awesome CSS into your LESS file and [let LESS process it](http://lesscss.org/#-importing).

Without it LESS won't be able to detect the classes you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the adequate bootstrap dependencies:

```
@import "bootstrap/variables.less";
@import "bootstrap/mixins.less";
@import "bootstrap/sprites.less";

.icon-domain { .icon-fire; }
.icon-group  { .icon-tags; }
```

Comment: I didn't clarify originally, but I did have all the bootstrap dependencies included. Thanks.